# Android Studio не видит R

Tags: android, java

В общем такие дела, не находит какой то файл и не видит R.
[Скрин](http://cs617530.vk.me/v617530352/148b9/BtsnuoY4XyI.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сдаётся мне, не находит он сам `aapt`. Проверьте его наличие по указанному в сообщении пути.